# Cannot Update Entity Using EF 6 - ObjectStateManager Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to update an entity using Entity Framework version 6.

I'm selecting the entity from the database like so...

```
 public T Find<T>(object id) where T : class
    {
        return this._dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
```

And updating the entity like so..

```
  public T Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        // get the primary key of the entity
        object id = this.GetPrimaryKeyValue(entity);

        // get the original entry
        T original = this._dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);


        if (original != null)
        {
            // do some automatic stuff here (taken out for example)

            // overwrite original property values with new values
            this._dbContext.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            this._dbContext.Entry(original).State = EntityState.Modified;

            // commit changes to database
            this.Save();

            // return entity with new property values
            return entity;
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

The GetPrimaryKeyValue function is as so...

```
 private object GetPrimaryKeyValue<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this._dbContext).ObjectContext
            .ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntry(entity);

        return objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
    }
```

**Just for clarity**. I'm selecting the original entry out as I need to perform some concurrency logic (that Ive taken out). I'm not posting that data with the entity and need to select it manually out of the DB again to perform the checks.

I know the GetPrimaryKeyValue function is not ideal if there's more than one primary key on the entity. I just want it to work for now.

When updating, entity framework coughs up the error below when trying to execute the GetPrimaryKeyValue function.

**The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'NAME_OF_ENTITY_IT_CANNOT_FIND'**

I've written many repositories before and I've never had this issue, I cannot seem to find why its not working (hence the post).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Steve

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. Is T entity in your change tracker? Because if it is, then calling _dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id) is not going to make a database query. It is going to look in the change tracker to see if it's already there (which it would be) and then give you that same entity. So original and entity would be the same reference at this point.

Comment: Related to the above comment, if T entity getting passed into your Update method is *not* in the change tracker, then you can't call CurrentValues() on it.

Comment: Hi Dismissile. Even after I take out all the code and just leave in 'this._dbContext.Entry(ENTITY).State = EntityState.Modified;'. I still get the error. 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.' Does this mean that its already a part of the change tracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are having issues getting the PK from the entity being passed in. Instead of trying to  go through EF to get this data you could either use their Key attribute or create your own and just use reflection to collect what the key names are. This will also allow you to retrieve multiple keys if it is needed. Below is an example I created inside of LinqPad, you should be able to set it to "Program" mode and paste this in and see it work. Hack the code up and use what you may. I implemented an IEntity but it is not required, and you can change the attribute to anything really.

Here are the results:

```
Keys found: 
CustomIdentifier
LookASecondKey
```

Here is the code:

```
// this is just a usage demo
void Main()
{
    // create your object from wherever
    var car = new Car(){ CustomIdentifier= 1, LookASecondKey="SecretKey", Doors=4, Make="Nissan", Model="Altima" };

    // pass the object in
    var keys = GetPrimaryKeys<Car>(car);

    // you have the list of keys now so work with them however
    Console.WriteLine("Keys found: ");  
    foreach(var k in keys)
            Console.WriteLine(k);   
}

// you probably want to use this method, add whatever custom logic or checking you want, maybe put
private IEnumerable<string> GetPrimaryKeys<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntity
{
    // place to store keys
    var keys = new List<string>();

    // loop through each propery on the entity
    foreach(var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        // check for the custom attribute you created, replace "EntityKey" with your own
        if(prop.CustomAttributes.Any(p => p.AttributeType.Equals(typeof(EntityKey))))
            keys.Add(prop.Name);
    }

    // check for key and throw if not found (up to you)
    if(!keys.Any())
        throw new Exception("No EntityKey attribute was found, please make sure the entity includes this attribute on at least on property.");

    // return all the keys
    return keys;
}

// example of the custom attribute you could use
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class EntityKey : Attribute
{

}

// this interface is not NEEDED but I like to restrict dal to interface
public interface IEntity { }

// example of your model
public class Car : IEntity
{
    [EntityKey] // add the attribure to property
    public int CustomIdentifier {get;set;}

    [EntityKey] // i am demonstrating multiple keys but you can have just one
    public string LookASecondKey {get;set;}

    public int Doors {get;set;}
    public string Make {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi Tony. Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this and I get the following error. 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.' So this tell me that its already attached to the context right?!?

Comment: Yeah the entity is valid but when SaveChanges() is called it doesn't error, but also doesn't update the database.

Comment: Apologies, to correct the above comment Im not even getting the original as its blowing up when i try and grab the primary key value from the posted entity (which should be a part of the context already)

Comment: Just to clarify. The Save() method basically executes a dbContext.SaveChanges() sub. I cannot get the original as when i attempt to get the primary key name (ID) from the entity variable it gives the  The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'NAME_OF_ENTITY_IT_CANNOT_FIND' error.

Comment: Hi Tony. Thanks for helping me with this it has really got me stumped. Ive tried to attach the entity within the GetPrimaryKeyValue function but I get this error. 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'. I am considering using reflection now but the whole point of me writing it in this manor was to avoid hard coding property names - if (propertyname == 'ID') etc

Comment: I have updated my answer, I am going to delete the conversations above that I have made since SO is complaining at me to open a chat  lol. The answer I have provided is the assist with getting the PK without using EF, let me know if they helps with your updating.